# Sistema de Locadoras de veículos em pascal

Tags: pascal

Quero as instruções  de como fazer uma locadora de veículos, como o meu código deve funcionar? Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Andrey, o SOPT funciona muito melhor se você tiver uma dúvida concreta a respeito do que quer fazer, ou um erro que está efetivamente acontecendo. Sua pergunta, atualmente, pede a solução de muitos problemas diferentes, sem fornecer detalhes sobre onde exatamente você está tendo dificuldades. Leia [este post](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/911/12) sobre perguntas "Amplas demais" e tente refazer sua pergunta. Tenho certeza de que vai conseguir ajuda. Bem vindo ao SOPT!

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente dizendo você deverá criar um vetor de registro que conterá os seguintes dados: *modelo do carro, marca, valor da diária, situação (**Disponível** ou **Alugado**), cliente atual e quantidade de diárias*.

Considere que o programa possua o cadastro dos clientes com *código*, *nome* e *telefone*.

**Cadastro de veículo**: Para cadastrar os dados de um veículo em uma das posições disponíveis, quando o programa for iniciado, a primeira posição deve ser inicializada com o nome *Disponível* e demais dados com zero. Sempre que for cadastrado um novo veículo, a posição seguinte deve ser inicializada com o nome *Disponível* e demais dados com zero (*exceto se exceder a capacidade do vetor*).

**Saída de veículo**: Para registrar a saída de um veículo o usuário deve indicar o *modelo do carro, o nome do cliente que está locando o carro e a quantidade de diárias solicitadas*.

Caso o carro esteja disponível, deve alterar a situação para alugado e registrar os demais dados. Se o carro já estiver alugado, o programa deve exibir uma mensagem informando isso e retornar ao menu principal.

**Devolução de veículo**: Para registrar a devolução de um veículo o usuário deverá pesquisar o modelo do carro. Ao encontrar, deverá exibir na tela o nome do cliente, o modelo do carro e o valor total da locação. Após isso, deve modificar a situação do carro para disponível.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
program locadora_auto;
uses crt;

type cadastro_locadora=record
        modelo_carro:string;
        marca:string;
        valor_diaria:real;
        situacao:char;
        cliente_atual:string;
        quantidade_diaria:integer;
   end;
   {Criação de um tipo registro para o cadastro da locadora}

   vet1=array [1..10]of cadastro_locadora;
   {Criação de um tipo vetor de tamanho 10 do tipo cadastro_locadora,
   para facilitar o desenvolvimento do programa}

var vetor:vet1;                //vetor - Criação de um vetor do tipo vet1 para o armazenamento dos cadastros
    cont,cont2,m,j:integer;    //Cont - Conta o número de posições utilizadas do vetor
                               //Cont2 - Um contador para saber se o registro digitado encontra-se no vetor (nesse caso soma +1), pra fazer a verificação - Se cont2=0 e o vetor se encontrar na última posição, o programa imprimirá um texto alegando que o registro nao se encontra no vetor.
                               //m - Criado para a leitura e verificação dos índices do menu
                               //j - Criado para uso do laço de repetição FOR
    nome_carro:string;         //nome_carro - Criado para receber o nome do carro para verificar se o texto digitado bate com o salvo no vetor

{Inicializa todos os itens do registro conforme pedido}
procedure inicializa(var vet:vet1;i:integer);
begin
   vet[i].modelo_carro:='0';
   vet[i].marca:='0';
   vet[i].valor_diaria:=0;
   vet[i].situacao:='D';
   vet[i].cliente_atual:='0';
   vet[i].quantidade_diaria:=0;
end;

{Faz a atribuição dos nomes e valores a suas devidas variáveis}
procedure cadastro(var vet:vet1;i:integer);
begin
   writeln('Modelo do carro: ');
   readln(vet[i].modelo_carro);
   vet[i].modelo_carro:=upcase(vet[i].modelo_carro);
   writeln('Marca do carro: ');
   readln(vet[i].marca);
   vet[i].marca:=upcase(vet[i].marca);
   write('Valor da diaria: R$');
   read(vet[i].valor_diaria);
   vet[i].situacao:='D';
   vet[i].cliente_atual:='0';
   vet[i].quantidade_diaria:=0;
end;

{Armazena no vetor o nome do cliente e o numero de diarias e muda a situação do veículo para alugado}
procedure saida(var vet:vet1;i:integer);
begin
   vet[i].situacao:='A';
   writeln('Nome do cliente: ');
   readln(vet[i].cliente_atual);
   repeat
   begin
      writeln('Numero de diarias: ');
      readln(vet[i].quantidade_diaria);
   end;
   until (vet[i].quantidade_diaria<30);

end;

{Imprime os dados do cliente, o valor total da locação, e muda a situação do carro para disponível}
procedure devolucao(var vet:vet1;i:integer);
begin
   writeln('Nome do cliente: ', vet[i].cliente_atual);
   writeln('Modelo atual: ', vet[i].modelo_carro);
   writeln('Valor total da locacao: R$', (vet[i].valor_diaria*vet[i].quantidade_diaria):2:2);
   vet[i].situacao:='D';
   vet[i].cliente_atual:='0';
   vet[i].quantidade_diaria:=0;
   readln;
end;

{Apenas exibe o menu na tela}
procedure menu();
begin
   writeln('[1] - Cadastro de veiculo');
   writeln('[2] - Saida de veiculo');
   writeln('[3] - Devolucao de veiculo');
   writeln('[4] - Sair');
end;

begin
   cont:=1;
   repeat
   begin
      clrscr;
      menu();
      readln(m);
      if m=1 then //cadastro de veículo
      begin
         clrscr;
         inicializa(vetor,cont);
         cadastro(vetor,cont);
         cont:=cont+1;
         inicializa(vetor,cont);
         cont2:=0;
      end
      else if m=2 then  //saída de veículo
      begin
         clrscr;
         writeln('Digite o modelo do carro: ');
         readln(nome_carro);
         nome_carro:=upcase(nome_carro);
         for j:=1 to 10 do
         begin
            if vetor[j].modelo_carro=nome_carro then  //se o nome do carro digitado está cadastrado no sistema
            begin
               writeln;
               saida(vetor,j);
               cont2:=cont2+1;
            end;
            if (cont2=0) and (j=10) then  //se tiver na ultima posição do vetor e o contador cont2=0, não existe o carro cadastrado no sistema
            begin
               writeln;
               writeln('Modelo nao cadastrado!');
               readln;
            end;
         end;
      end
      else if m=3 then   //devolução de veículo
      begin
         clrscr;
         writeln('Digite o modelo do carro: ');
         readln(nome_carro);
         nome_carro:=upcase(nome_carro);
         for j:=1 to 10 do
         begin
            if vetor[j].modelo_carro=nome_carro then  //se o nome do carro digitado está cadastrado no sistema
            begin
               writeln;
               devolucao(vetor,j);
               cont2:=cont2+1;
            end;
            if (cont2=0) and (j=10) then  //se tiver na ultima posição do vetor e o contador cont2=0, não existe o carro cadastrado no sistema
            begin
               writeln;
               writeln('Modelo nao cadastrado!');
               readln;
            end;
         end;
      end;
   end;
   until (m=4);
end.
```

<sub>[**Fonte**](http://pascal22a.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/trabalho-de-aed-ll-exercicio-1.html)</sub>

Comment: Tem gente que vota negativo por causa da pergunta ser ruim. Isso foi comentado no meta há alguns dias. Paciência.